# No file path in dynamic web project in java eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse. When I'm executing just WordFreq.java it works. If I want to execute same code in MyServlet.java > doGet method, I get this error: HTTP Status 500 - text.txt (The system cannot find the file specified).
I copied my file (text.txt) everywhere :

- The project root folder
- The WebContent folder
- The src folder
- Any subdirectory in my project.

and still get this error.

Note: my workspace is in D:/.... and my Apache server is on C:/...
I tried to change to full path but still doesn't work.

WordFreq.java

```
package cpd;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordFreq {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File("text.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        String content = new Scanner(file1).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        CezarBun cezar = new CezarBun();
        System.out.println(cezar.criptare(content, 3));
        System.out.println("Frecventa literelor");
        System.out.println();
        int nextChar;
        char ch;
        double[] count = new double[26];
        while ((nextChar = in.read()) != -1) {
            ch = ((char) nextChar);
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                count[ch - 'a']++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%c %d", i + 'a', (int) count[i]);
            System.out.println("Frecventa: " + count[i] / file1.length() * 100 + "%");
        }
        in.close();
        try {
            /*create a buffered reader that connects to the console, we use it so we can 
             read lines*/

            BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            //read a line from the console
            String lineFromInput = in2.readLine();
            //create an print writer for writing to a file
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
            System.setOut(out);
            //output to the file a line
            out.println(lineFromInput);
            //close the stream
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
        }
    }
}
```

MyServlet.java

```
package cpd;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     * response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("A pornit servlet-ul" + "<br />");
    //inceput wordfreq
        File file1 = new File("text.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        String content = new Scanner(file1).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        CezarBun cezar = new CezarBun();
        System.out.println(cezar.criptare(content, 3));
        System.out.println("Frecventa literelor");
        System.out.println();
        int nextChar;
        char ch;
        double[] count = new double[26];
        while ((nextChar = in.read()) != -1) {
            ch = ((char) nextChar);
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                count[ch - 'a']++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%c %d", i + 'a', (int) count[i]);
            System.out.println("        Frecventa:      " + count[i] / file1.length() * 100 + "%");

        }
        in.close();
        try {
            //create a buffered reader that connects to the console, we use it so we can read lines
            BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            //read a line from the console
            String lineFromInput = in2.readLine();
            //create an print writer for writing to a file
            PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
            System.setOut(out2);
            //output to the file a line
            out2.println(lineFromInput);
            //close the file (VERY IMPORTANT!)
            out2.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
        }
    //sfarsit wordfreq
    // freq = new WordFreqBun();
        //freq.wf();
        out.print("<br />");
        out.print("<a href='http://localhost:8080/CpdApplication/'>Inapoi la meniu</a>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     * response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your file as a resource using the ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(), the file can be located anywhere in your web application. It is recommended to keep it under the /WEB-INF directory if you don't want browers being able to access it.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

[ServletContext.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) : Returns a URL to the resource that is mapped to the given path.

[ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) : 
Returns the resource located at the named path as an InputStream object.